# Need help with simple "if statement" checks to output particlular CPT data depending on what client uploads/fills out

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, post-thumbnails

In short, Im not a master of PHP yet and Im not entirely sure how to place a series of checks (if statements) in my template so that it will know what to display depending on what the client uploads/fills out in the CPT ive created...

What Im trying to have it do is:
(1) Check to see if there is a URL entered (custom meta box) - if so, display it and wrap it around the featured image...
(2) If no URL is chosen - then only display the featured image by itself...
(3) and lastly, if no banner image is created at all - then display a default image....

Thanks for the help!

Here is what I have thus far which is currently not working:

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_box_topbanner_url', true))?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'meta_box_topbanner_url', true); ?>" target="_blank">
       <?php the_post_thumbnail('top-banner-img', array('class' => 'top-banner-img', 'title' => '')); ?>
    </a>

<?php elseif the_post_thumbnail('top-banner-img', array('class' => 'top-banner-img', 'title' => '')); ?>

<?php else '<img src="images/epr_bannder_default.jpg" alt="epr_bannder_default" width="960" height="200" />' ?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what *isn't* working? What is the actual output that you get from this code?

Comment: Hi, it actually ends up breaking the entire page but I cant pinpoint where in my code is causing it. I think its possibly my `elseif` but like I said I just pieced this together the best I could without knowing the correct conventions for writing it.

Comment: Well, we need to know if it is a *PHP syntax* issue - in which case the question is out of scope for WPSE - or if it is a WordPress-specific issue, such as usage of `get_post_meta()`, etc.

Comment: Not sure, but I believe the root of my problem lies more in using correct PHP writing conventions rather than anything else...but being that this is directly related to my wordpress template I didnt think it was inappropriate to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some basic syntax problems. Your `elseif` statement wasn't actually checking anything and wasn't properly wrapped in parenthesis. The logic more appropriately checks if the first condition is true, then if the second condition is true, and finally if all else fails, display the hard coded image.

```
<?php $meta_box_topbanner_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_box_topbanner_url', true ); ?>
<?php $post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>

<?php if ( !empty( $meta_box_topbanner_url ) ) : ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'meta_box_topbanner_url', true); ?>" target="_blank">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('top-banner-img', array('class' => 'top-banner-img', 'title' => '')); ?>
    </a>

<?php elseif ( !empty( $post_thumbnail ) ) : ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail('top-banner-img', array('class' => 'top-banner-img', 'title' => '')); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <img src="images/epr_bannder_default.jpg" alt="epr_bannder_default" width="960" height="200" />' ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

I removed a redundant check from the `elseif` condition.

Comment: Would you mind adding some descriptive text explaining what is different about this code?

Comment: Yep, that seems to work @develpdaly, though the last check is not grabbing the backup image. (I checked and my image path is correct for the record)...

Additionally, is there a more consolidated way to do this or is this my only option?

Comment: I think that's about as simple as you'll get it. Check line 2 where I setup `get_the_post_thumbnail()` because you may need to make some changes to that function's arguments. It is simply getting the thumbnail without any restrictions.

Comment: hmm...well my first thought would be that the default image is not actually a featured image/thumbnail so I suppose that would be the first logical reason for it not to grab the appropriate image if thats how your function is written to work. This image simply resides in my images folder.